# How to know which item was clicked, if item contains a custom View class, which implements own onClick method?

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view, custom-adapter

I have custom View class, which contains 2 TextViews, RatingBar, ImageView and 4 ImageButtons. When i click this View, it expand and these ImageButtons will appear. If i click one more time , it returns to its original state. All work great.
But i try to make ListView of these custom Views, so XML-file with item contains only this custom View.

I have custom Adapter for my List:

```
public class CustomViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Note[] items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomViewAdapter(Context context,Note[] elements){
    this.items=elements;
    this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     CustomView view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = (CustomView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemoflist, null);

    } else {
        view = (CustomView) convertView;

    }
     Note item = (Note) getItem(position);
    view.showNote(item);
    return view;
  }
}
```

MainActivity inherited from ListActivity. Of course, OnItemClick doesn't work, while Item is clickable.

So how should i know item's position which have been clicked to save expandable state of items?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle click listener of particular item from your Custom view in listview then handle onClickListener for items in Custom view in your CustomViewAdapter. For items position, in getView method of your adapter you get the position as an argument of getView method.